# Whats wrong with this regex for date/time

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I've found a good regex at http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=233. For easy reference, it's

```
^([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([2][01]|[1][6-9])\d{2}(\s([0]\d|[1][0-2])(\:[0-5]\d){1,2})*\s*([aApP][mM]{0,2})?$
```

I know nothing about regexes, so I don't know how to debug this at all. I'm getting a date/time string from this jQuery plugin http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ which is in this format:

```
"09/02/2012 14:51" //Fail
```

However, the above is an example of a failing string, although it seems fine to me. When I get the current time, it passes:

```
"12/22/2012 00:01" //Pass
```

Can anyone see a problem with this regex?

Comment: Learn regex - it is a valuable tool.

Comment: I think your examples are switched. The one that fails is the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That regex only accepts hours in am/pm format, from `0` to `12`:

```
((\s([0]\d|[1][0-2])(\:[0-5]\d){1,2})*\s*([aApP][mM]{0,2})?)
     ^-------------
     This block represents the hours, and its range is 0-12
```

To consider the hour in day, from 0 to 23, add the following to the hour part:

`(0\d|1[0-9]|2[0-3])`

Yielding the final regex:

```
/^([0]\d|[1][0-2])\/([0-2]\d|[3][0-1])\/([2][01]|[1][6-9])\d{2}(\s(([0]\d|[1][0-2])|(0\d|1[0-9]|2[0-3]))(\:[0-5]\d){1,2})*\s*([aApP][mM]{0,2})?$
```

Comment: Oh, duh.. I was looking at another regex that accepted 24hr time, and didn't even realize I picked one that _didn't_. Thanks!